# Turn off line wrapping when running git grep

Tags: git, git-grep, terminal.app

Sometimes I do a `git grep`, and there's that one line which is so long it takes up half a page or more because of line wrapping. How can I tell `git grep` to turn of line wrapping, instead requiring me to scroll to the right if I want to see the rest of a long line?

I'm using Terminal on OSX, if that's relevant. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep didn't indicate which program the `git grep` command  outputs to, if any.

Comment: Untested, but pretty sure it's enough to set `GIT_PAGER="less -S"`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Works For Me(TM).

Comment: @WilliamPursell can you turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git grep` filters its output through the program set in the environment variable `GIT_PAGER`, so you just need to set that variable to an appropriate pager.  Or, set your environment so that the pager it uses exhibits the behavior you want.  For example, either `GIT_PAGER="less -S"` or `LESS=-S` should work (assuming your default `PAGER` is `less`).  You need to put those in the environment, so you might either put `export GIT_PAGER` or `export LESS` in your shell startup scripts, or run `GIT_PAGER="less -S" git grep ...`